# What are the advantages and disadvantages of higher order neuron activation functions?

Tags: neural-networks, activation-function

I've been reading about different types of neurons that the traditional linear one. One example I came across is the Sigma-Pi neuron, where the activation function includes higher order terms, such as

[image: example activation]

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using neurons like that? Why do we tend not to use them in favour of the traditional wX(+b)?